# Why does The Unarchiver need to make a network request when unzipping a file?

Tags: network, rar

As shown LuLu detects a connection, and despite blocking it, the rar file was unzipped.

[image: Screenshot of LuLu]

Comment: You should [contact MacPaw's support directly](https://macpaw.com/support/contact) and ask them. They are best placed to answer this question – and, when they reply, please share the response here for others.

Comment: You'll probably get pointed to https://macpaw.com/policy The Appstore page says they collect Diagnostics.

Comment: Also, port 53 is for DNS lookup, and the IPv6 might be your local router (especially as the reverse name is 'homeportal'), or assigned DNS provider. That isn't where the software is actually trying to get to..

Comment: The likelihood is it wanted to check if there was an update available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unarchiver.app directly installed from the webstie seems to do two kind of connections:

[image]

- The first three (4, 68, 69) are "phone home" requests which seem to track that a user started the application and what they did with it. Each request itself consists of some identifiers (probably to identify the user) and the activity taken, see [here](https://gist.github.com/nohillside/d3eac4d97ca23bc6a7c3368c3d23f06a) for a full example.

[image]

- The last two check for update (it's actually just one request, #73 gets redirected to Amazon AWS)

The connection to sentry.io can be blocked (I used Little Snitch, you could also block it on your router or similar), it doesn't seem to impact the application.

Comment: Everyone should block sentry.io as a matter of course.  No developer is entitled to telemetry.  They can ask, maybe.